# Standard deviation of kinetic energy approaches average kinetic energy

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

I have a simulated system of lots of particles modeled as circles moving in 2 dimensions. They bounce off each other and off of walls. Momentum and kinetic energy are conserved.

I noticed that the standard deviation of the kinetic energy of the system seems to always converge to the average kinetic energy of the system.

What is the name of this phenomenon?

Answer (score 5):

[It's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble) an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Mean,_variance,_moments,_and_median).